# How to create a badge inside another?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have submiited an image with a badge inside another badge and i am trying to figure out how they did it?

[image: Badge inside of another badge]

Comment: I don't think the larger one is a Bootstrap badge, it is styled slightly differently - look at the gradient. I reckon it's just a custom styled `span`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I believe you are correct but I am still interested with how they achieved it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explanation

In order to achieve the desired behavior, use the property `position: relative` in your wrapper element and use `position: absolute` in the child element.

Then position the child element in the top/right corner with `top: 0` and `right: 0`.

The last part will require the CSS3 property `transform` with the `translate` attribute. You can read more about it in [`CSS3 2D Transforms`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) or [`transform | CSS-Tricks`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/).

We will use `transform: translate(50%, -50%)` here. The first `50%` means that the element will be dislocated half it's own width to the right, and the second `50%` means that the element will be dislocated half it's own height up.

You could skip this part if your badge has a fixed width and/or height, and just use a fixed value.

## Example

```css
body {
  margin: 25px
}
.outter-badge {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
.inner-badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="badge outter-badge">badge
  <div class="badge inner-badge">1</div>
</div>

<div class="badge outter-badge">primary label
  <div class="label label-primary inner-badge">1</div>
</div>

<div class="badge outter-badge">success label
  <div class="label label-success inner-badge">1</div>
</div>

<div class="badge outter-badge">warning label
  <div class="label label-warning inner-badge">1</div>
</div>

<div class="badge outter-badge">danger label
  <div class="label label-danger inner-badge">1</div>
</div>

<div class="badge outter-badge">info label
  <div class="label label-info inner-badge">1</div>
</div>
```