# How to implement notification like icon/image

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to build a somewhat dynamic icon/image in the notification style common in mobile devices. I must clarify though that the primary display will be on desktops. The image will lie before some text
For example

[image]Some Text

This consists of 2 images: the telescope and the gear plus a number that is dynamic.

I am almost completely new to css, so I am struggling how to place the gear with respect to the telescope and how to scale the gear depending on the number (for example if the number is 10000 the gear needs to be larger than if it is 3).

Of course the whole combo needs to scale well with the screen size as well.
How to go about this in a somewhat elegant way?

My html looks like

```
<div class="sidebar-item active">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="lab-image"/>
                <span class="sidebar-item-title">Labs</span>
            </a>
</div>
```

but right now my lab-image is just the telescope image.

Comment: If you're using CSS that implies you're also using HTML, can you post the HTML you're using to create this icon construct?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: So whereabouts does the number of notifications come from; how should the CSS 'know' whether to show a `0`, `1`...? Where should the gear icon come from?

Comment: The gear and the telescope are for now fixed sized images. The number comes from the backend code and it changes depending on the user and other things.

Comment: But where does it get injected into the HTML; if it's not in the HTML (whether as a text-node, or an attribute-value) then CSS isn't going to 'see' it.

Comment: For now you can think of it as a hardcoded number like @bruce182 has in his answer say <p>1000</p>. Once hooked to the backend if will be accessed by angular from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a badge with a custom background-image
So, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026979/how-to-create-a-badge-inside-another) I've create this fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var cw = $('.inner-badge').width();
$('.inner-badge').css({'height':cw+'px'});
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 25px
}
.outter-badge {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 64px;
}
.inner-badge {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -25px;
  background-image: url('https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/174149/fancy-badge.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner-badge p{
  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outter-badge"> 
  <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i88396/icons8/ios7/Industry-Microscope.ico" alt="" height="64">
  <div class="inner-badge">
    <p>1000</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(intent);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(intent.getResources().getIdentifier(appIcon + "_transparent", "drawable", intent.getPackageName()));
}else{
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(intent.getResources().getIdentifier(appIcon, "drawable", intent.getPackageName()));
}
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(intent.getResources(), intent.getResources().getIdentifier(appIcon, "drawable", intent.getPackageName()));
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);
}
notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Sorry I should say that the display will be mainly on a desktop, but I am using a concept that is commonly  seen in mobile devices.